# How Can I Prevent the React Router 404 from Showing on All Pages?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
<Router>
    <Header />

    <Route exact={true} path="/">
      <Form />
    </Route>

    <Switch>
      <Route path="/login">
        <LoginTable />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/feedback">
        <Feedback />
      </Route>
      <Route path="*">
        <Four04 />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```

The `<Four04>` component is always showing at the bottom of each page.

My understanding was that a `<Switch>` would take the first available route and not end up in '404' area.

I have tried moving that '404' out of the `Switch`.

I have also tried adding `exact={true}` to the other components!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, actually, the issue was that the top `Route` was not in the `Switch` - NS Y I did that initially.

Answer (score 0):

I always set it up like:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } 
from "react-router-dom";
<Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/other" component={Other} />
      <Route component={NoMatch} /> 
   </Switch> 
</Router>
```

If no route matches, then it hits the NoMatch component

Comment: Use the configuration in my answer using your paths, import everything just like that, and then change paths with your paths, and lastly, add the 404 component like in my example